# Script for data_stamp when moving a row from one sheet to another

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

We use google sheets for our workbooks, and use scripts for a lot of the workflows.

In one of the workbooks we have a working script where based on a value in Column 20 it will move that row to the specified page from a dropdown in column 20. I need to modify it in order to also stamp the current date in column 8, when the script moves the row to a different page. (Regardless of whether there is a value there already)

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  // target sheet of move to named Acquired
  // test column with yes/no is col 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Erik" && r.getColumn() == 20 && r.getValue() == "Marcus") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Marcus");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
   }
}

OBS! This is what i have been trying with, but it is not working :(

  if(s.getName() == "Erik" && r.getColumn() == 20 && r.getValue() == "Iman") {
     var cellD2 = r.getColumn () == 8;  
   
    cellD2.setValue(new Date());
    

    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Iman");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
   }
```

Comment: is it supposed to send the data to the sheet called 'Iman' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You are close, the only problem is the definition of `cellD2`

To access a cell you need to use the method [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column).

To access the active row, you can use [getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow).

In your case it would be:

`var cellD2 = s.getRange(r.getRow(), 8);`